Does a mirror have an albedo of 0?
According to the Wikipedia definition of albedo, it measures the fraction of light that is diffusely reflected by a body.
Let's consider the visible light wavelenghts; is a mirror an object with an albedo of 0?

The ideal mirror has an albedo of 1. "Diffusively" should be interpreted as "integrating over the entire solid angle (and thus including any specular reflection)" rather than "excluding specular reflection," if that's the distinction you're referring to.

Indeed, I'm not sure there would be a way in practice to find diffuse reflection while excluding specular reflection. There's nothing that would preclude a diffused ray from emerging at the exact same angle as a reflected ray - subtracting the light exiting along the reflected angle from the total reflected light might under-count the contribution from diffuse.
